# How to read the content of these files?

Tags: decryption, encryption, decompress

I am looking for a way to read the content of these two files. If that is possible, please let me know.

Google Drive [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1N89Ey9RFeVgI335pCS4abQr3UtvmuX8_) for the files

Comment: Use a hexeditor of your choice. Where are those files from? Why do think they are compressed or encrypted?

Comment: Agreed, we need to know more information about these files. What sort of files are they? What software created them? What info do you want extracted? Do you know any other details that might be important?

Comment: @MerseyViking These two files are generated for each recording I do on my PVR device. The recorded media file can only be watched through the device and it is scrambled. I thought that the above generated files could have some specific information to unscramble the recording.

Comment: I suspect then that you'll be out of luck. The decryption keys will probably be stored on a secure chip in the PVR.